# Indikativ als Liedtitel

Tags: verb, lyrics

Titel von deutschsprachigen Liedern sind sehr oft

- Nominalphrasen ...

  > [Griechischer Wein](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBkPARPm-Mc) - Udo Jürgens
  >   [99 Luftballons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=La4Dcd1aUcE) - Nena
- ... Nomen ohne weitere Zusätze ...

  > [Millionär](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJSTBmM_B4o) - Die Prinzen
  >   [Fürstenfeld](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpRmP0XUVcA) - S.T.S
- ... Aufforderungen ...

  > [Zwickt’s mi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVoffqksUhc) - Wolfgang Ambros
  >   [Kauf mich!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_sDnAyObS0) - Die Toten Hosen
- ... manchmal auch Prädikative oder Präpositionalobjekte ...

  > [Verdamp lang her](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TB751ZCh_zU) - BAP
  >   [Unter die Haut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEid1xgBLHM) - Tim Bendzko feat. Cassandra Steen
- ... und sogar ganze Sätze ...

  > [Der Typ, der bei der GEMA die Titel eintippt, ist ein ganz blöder Penner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiOTKjXZaYI) - Eure Mütter
  >   [Wir sind jung und wir machen uns Sorgen über unsere Chancen auf dem Arbeitsmarkt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AoEYtqaiJk) - Peter Licht

... und viele andere grammatische Konstrukte.

Liedtitel, die nur aus Verben ohne ein Subjekt bestehen, sind selten, aber wenn sie vorkommen, stehen sie so gut wie immer in der Grundform, also im Infinitiv Präsens:

> [Lachen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gmdRebABbk) - Rosenstolz
>   [Tanzen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOEc04nVIeE) - Rockstroh

In Österreich wurde aber im August 2015 ein Lied im Wiener Dialekt veröffentlicht, das in Österreich 58 Wochen lang in den Top-80 (davon 5 Wochen auf Platz 1) blieb, dessen Titel nur aus einem Indikativ und einem Adverb besteht:

> [Ham kummst](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWgisTPKCdk) - Seiler und Speer

Der Titel *»ham kummst«* bedeutet auf Hochdeutsch: *»heim kommst«*. In dem Lied geht es um einen verheirateten Mann, der sich immer wieder die Nächte mit seinen Freunden um die Ohren schlägt, anstatt zu Hause bei seiner Frau zu sein. Im Refrain zitiert der Sänger seine Frau:

> Waunst amoi nu so **ham kummst,** sama gschiedane Leid.
>   Waunst amoi nu so **ham kummst,** host die Scheidung mei Freind!
>
> (Hochdeutsch):
>   Wenn du einmal noch so **heim kommst,** sind wir geschiedene Leute.
>   Wenn du einmal noch so **heim kommst,** hast du die Scheidung mein Freund! *( = ... reiche ich die Scheidung ein, mein Freund!)*

Ich würde nun gerne wissen, ob es auch andere Lieder gibt, deren Titel nur aus einem Indikativ (eventuell noch mit einem Adverb) besteht. (Es dürfen keine weitere Wörter vorhanden sein, die als Subjekt verstanden werden könnten.)

Comment: Wie wär's mit dem (*Unsinn als Liedtitel*): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6R8J8nW3D_Q

Comment: "dessen Titel nur aus einem **Infinitiv** und einem Adverb besteht" vs " ob es auch andere Leider gibt, deren Titel nur aus einem **Indikativ**" -> Im ersten Satz meintest du "Indikativ"? Oder wolltest du in beiden Fällen eher auf "konjugiert" raus?

Comment: @Em1: Das sollte im ersten Satz tatsächlich »nur aus einem **Indikativ** und einem Adverb« heißen. Ich habe es nun korrigiert. Aber du hast Recht, gemeint ist etwas allgemeiner »konjugierte Verbform«.

Comment: Die meisten Titel von Kunstwerken werden wohl Substantive sein. Vor diesem Hintergrund würde ich "Tanzen", "Lachen" usw. nicht als Infinitiv, sondern als substaniviertes Verb ("das Tanzen") sehen. Bei Liedern kommt es auch oft vor, dass die Anfangsworte einer Strophe, des Refrains oder eines ähnlich auffälligen Teils als Titel genommen werden. Zu dieser Kategorie zählen z.B. "Kauf mich!" oder "Verdammt lang her". Ich gehe davon aus, dass Liedtitel, die in keine beider Kategorien passen, sehr selten sind.

Answer (score 2):

- **Die Toten Hosen** mehrere Beispiele dazu aus dem Album Auswärtsspiel: "Schwimmen", "Drüber reden", "Schöner warten".
- **Knorkator** – *Und ging* (enthält zwar zusätzlich zum konjugierten Verb die Konjunktion *und,* die aber sicher kein Subjekt ist)
- Ähnlich ungewöhnlich ist vermutlich "Die da" von den **Fantastischen Vier**, wo nur ein Demonstrativpronomen mit einem Adverb vorhanden ist.
- **Zabine**, Album Transalpin: *Guat liabn*
- **Wir sind Helden**: "Müssen nur wollen" (1. Person Plural ist gemeint). So halb passend, weil das finite Hilfsverb fehlt: "Für nichts garantieren" (Ich kann...), "Gekommen um zu bleiben" (Wir sind ...)

*Da diese Frage eine Liste als Antwort erwartet, ist diese Antwort ist ein Community-Wiki. Schreibe bitte keine weiteren Antworten für neue Liedtitel, sondern füge sie dieser Liste hinzu.*